# How to map physical addresses to virtual addresses with different sizes?

Tags: paging, virtual-memory

I'm currently studying how to map virtual addresses to physical addresses with paging, and it makes sense when the length of physical addresses = length of the virtual addresses for example:

If we have 32 bit virtual and physical addresses with 4KB page sizes, then our page offset would be 12 bits and our PPNs and VPNs would both be 20 bits.

However, if our physical addresses are not the same length, let's say 12 bits for physical and 16 bits for virtual with 128B page sizes. Our offset would be 7 bits, leaving 5 bit PPNs and 9 bit VPNs.

Is this correct? If so, how would you do the mappings then? Would you just take the first 5 bits of the VPN and index it into a page table and immediately find the correct page, while completely ignoring the remaining 4 bits?

Answer (score 0):

You have something messed up here. The page table entry consists of the page frame offset and some number of control bits.

If you have a 4KB page in 32-bits, your logical addresses are a 20-bit virtual page index and a 12-bit byte offset.

If your hardware uses 12-bits for the control bits, the logical and physical addresses will be the same length. If your hardware uses fewer than 12 bits for the offset, it could use the extra bits to index physical page frames. In case, the physical addressing is larger than the logical addressing.